# Creating a loop with dnorm and adding result to a table

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

I have a table with 1000 rows where each row is a different variable. Every row includes a name, value, mean and standard deviation.

```
Table_1 <- data.table(Variables = c("a","b","c"), Value = 1000, mean = -(3:1), sd   = 2)
```

My table looks like this:

```
Variables Value  mean sd
a         1000   -3   2
b         1000   -2   2
c         1000   -1   2
...
```

For each row I want to add the result of the following:

```
set.seed(1)
sq1 <- seq(from = -3, to = 3, length.out = 180)
rn1 <- dnorm(sq1, mean = Table_1$mean[1], sd = Table_1$sd[1])
rn2 <- Table_1$Value[1] * rn1/sum(rn1)
```

I have tried a loop but I have a problem with the rn1 part and can't even get to rn2 part. The following loop is giving me NULL.

```
Table_2 <- for(i in 1:3) {dnorm(sq1, mean = Table_1$mean[i], sd = Table_1$sd[i])}
```

Results are supposed to look like this, but output can also be in a seperate table or in long form:

```
Variables Value  mean sd 1          2          3          ...
a         1000   -3   2  13.3182941 13.3164238 13.3108143 ...
b         1000   -2   2  8.5720647  8.6429855  8.7120456  ...
c         1000   -1   2  4.939155   5.021927   5.104651   ...
```

Do you have any idea how to put it into a loop or apply function or map function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using a loop in this case.
One alternative would be `lapply`:

```
my_fun <- function(value, mean, sd) {
  rn1 <- dnorm(seq(from = -3, to = 3, length.out = 180), mean, sd)
  return(value * rn1 / sum(rn1))
}

lapply(1:3, function(i) my_fun(Table_1$Value[i], Table_1$mean[i], Table_1$sd[-1]))
```

Another solution would use the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
new_data <- tibble(Variables = c("a","b","c"), value = 1000,
                   mean = (-3):(-1), sd = 2) %>%
  mutate(result = pmap(list(value, mean, sd), my_fun))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Variables value  mean    sd result     
  <chr>     <dbl> <int> <dbl> <list>     
1 a          1000    -3     2 <dbl [180]>
2 b          1000    -2     2 <dbl [180]>
3 c          1000    -1     2 <dbl [180]>
```

In the last example for each row a new column result is created which contains the values. To access these values you can use `new_data$result[[1]]`.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, I have tested both solutions and the second one works better for me. Also thank you for edits in my question, I will look out for these mistakes in the future.